# Избранные - Ограничить количество выводимых элементов в зависимости от ширины блока

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Задача реализовать "Избранное" как браузере, строка с кнопками, которые если не помещаются уходят в dropdown.

Если задать overflow: hidden не совсем понятно как определить какие элементы помещаются, а какие нет, и соответственно распределять по спискам выводимых элементов и элементов для dropdown.

---

По предложенному методу попробовал написать директиву. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что уж больно долго обновляется DOM и из-за этого код работает некорректно.

В случае если убираются 2 элемента, ширина второго не записывается из-за того, что 1 элемент еще в DOM. Таймеры не помогли ...

Может что-то не так делаю, подскажите.

```
App.directive('Favorites', function(){
    // Runs during compile
    return {

        controller: [

            '$scope',
            '$element',
            'Stat',
            'Favorites',

            function ($scope, $element, Stat, Favorites) {

                var $elem = $($element),
                    starEl = $elem.find('.fn-favorite-start'),
                    moreEl = $elem.find('.fn-favorites-more');

                $scope.storeList = Favorites.getList();

                $scope.favoriteList = Stat.getByKeys($scope.storeList);
                $scope.showList = Stat.getByKeys($scope.storeList);
                $scope.moreList = [];
                $scope.itemsWidth = {};

                var calcWidth = function() {

                    var elemWidth = $elem.width(),
                        starWidth = starEl.outerWidth(true),
                        moreWidth = moreEl.outerWidth(true),
                        navWidth = 0;

                    var availablespace = elemWidth - starWidth - moreWidth;

                    $elem.find('> .fn-favorite-item').each(function() {
                        navWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
                    });

                    if(navWidth > availablespace) {

                        $scope.$apply(function() {

                            var lastItem = $($elem.find('.fn-favorite-item').last()),
                                ID = lastItem.data('id'),
                                lastItemWidth = lastItem.outerWidth(true);

                            $scope.itemsWidth[ID] = lastItemWidth;
                            $scope.moreList = $scope.showList.slice(-1).concat($scope.moreList);
                            $scope.showList = $scope.showList.slice(0,-1);

                            calcTimer = $timeout(calcWidth,500);
                        });

                    }else{
                        var firstModeWidth = $scope.itemsWidth[$scope.moreList.ID];

                        if (navWidth + firstModeWidth < availablespace) {
                            $scope.$apply(function() {
                                $scope.showList.push($scope.moreList[0]);
                                $scope.moreList = $scope.moreList.slice(1);
                            });
                        }

                    }
                };

                var calcTimer = null;

                angular.element(window).on('resize', function() {

                    if(calcTimer) {
                        cancel(calcTimer);
                    }

                    calcTimer = $timeout(calcWidth,500);
                });

                /* Events */
            }],
        restrict: 'E', // E = Element, A = Attribute, C = Class, M = Comment
        templateUrl: 'directives/favorites/template.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            _log('--- directives -> favorites');
        }
    };
});
```

template:

```
<div class="inline ui-favorites">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star yellow icon-favorite fn-favorite-start" aria-hidden="true"></i>

    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs ui-favorite-item fn-favorite-item hidden-sm" ng-repeat="userItem in showList" data-id="{{userItem.ID}}">
        <a ng-href="users/view/{{userItem.ID}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user "></i> {{userItem.TITLE}}</a>
        <button type="button" class="ui-favorites_remove-item btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="removeFromFavorites(userItem.ID)" title='Удалить "{{userItem.TITLE}}" из избранных'>&times;</button>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-favorites-more fn-favorites-more ui-favorite-item" ng-if="moreList.length">
        <a href="" class="fn-favorites-more__toggle ui-favorites-more__toggle"> {{moreList.length}} &#9660;</a>
        <div class="ui-favorites-more-list">
            <ul>
                <li class="clearfix" ng-repeat="userItem in moreList">

                    <a class="ui-favorites-more__delete" href="" ng-click="removeFromFavorites(userItem.ID)" title='Удалить "{{userItem.TITLE}}" из избранных'>&times;</a>

                    <a class="ui-favorites-more__move" ng-href="users/view/{{userItem.ID}}">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user "></i>
                        <span ng-bind="userItem.TITLE"></span>
                    </a>


                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="visible-sm-block visible-xs-block">
        Избранные ...
    </div>

    <small ng-if="favoriteList.length==0">Избранных пользоветелей нет ...</small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

я сделал демо

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var item_width = $('#menu_ul li').width();
  var item_count = ($("#menu_ul li").length);
  var nav_width_og = $('.menu').width();
  var nav_width = $('.menu').width();

  if ((item_width * (item_count + 1)) > nav_width) {
    $('#more').appendTo('body');
    $('#more').hide();
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < item_count; i++) {
    nav_width = $('.menu').width();
    item_width = $('#menu_ul li').width();
    item_count = ($("#menu_ul li").length);

    if (nav_width < (item_width * item_count)) {
      $('#menu_ul li').not('#more').last().appendTo($('.overflow'));

      $('#more').appendTo($('#menu_ul'));
      $('#more').show();
    }
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {

    nav_width = $('.menu').width();
    item_width = $('#menu_ul li').width();
    item_count = ($("#menu_ul li").length);

    if (nav_width < (item_width * item_count)) {
      $('#menu_ul li').not('#more').last().appendTo($('.overflow'));

      $('#more').appendTo($('#menu_ul'));
      $('#more').show();
    }

    if (nav_width > (item_width * item_count) + (item_width - 1)) {
      $('.overflow li').last().appendTo($('#menu_ul'));

      $('#more').appendTo($('#menu_ul'));
    }

    if (nav_width == nav_width_og) {
      $('#more').appendTo('body');
      $('#more').hide();
    }

  });

  $('#more').click(function() {
    $('.overflow').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  font-size: 0px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.overflow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}
.overflow li {
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
}
#more {
  background: blue;
  display: none;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul id="menu_ul">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
    <li>item6</li>

    <li id="more">more</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="overflow">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Идею понял, попробую на angular реализовать.

Comment: спасибо. правда ширина элементов у меня не фиксированная ... есть идеи.

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh можно посмотреть это демо http://codepen.io/moy/pen/qOYeqN

Comment: благодарю. Примерно так же подумал сделать.

Comment: не получилось ...